# Noun + to + infinitive

Tags: meaning, phrases

I've read an article recently which has the title "Intel To Release Most Powerful Mainstream Processor Ever To Beat AMD" ([link](https://www.forbes.com/sites/antonyleather/2018/03/22/intel-to-release-most-powerful-mainstream-processor-ever-to-beat-amd/#59dea1f96ac6)). I feel something is missed between "Intel" & "To". So the question what does "Intel To Release" mean and what's the name of this kind of construction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "Prices to be set..." used in this sentence instead of "Prices will be set..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412990/why-is-prices-to-be-set-used-in-this-sentence-instead-of-prices-will-be-se) See also [To + verb in sentence without any other verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209197). As indicated in the linked posts, the missing word between "Intel" and "to" is "is"; "Intel is to release..." means "Intel will release..."; and the name of the construction is "headlinese".

Comment: When it comes to news headlines, throw all grammar rules out the window, it's like note-taking.

Answer (score 1):

This is non-standard English, which is common in headlines. [According to Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/types-of-english-formal-informal-etc/newspaper-headlines):

> *"The main features of the grammar of headlines are the use of a series of nouns and the use of ellipsis (leaving out words which are not necessary)"*
>
> [...]
>
> *"Headlines often use the to-infinitive form to refer to future events"*

For more information, also read their [article on *ellipsis*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/ellipsis).

#### Attribution

[1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/types-of-english-formal-informal-etc/newspaper-headlines) "Newspaper Headlines - English Grammar Today." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed March 24, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/types-of-english-formal-informal-etc/newspaper-headlines.

Answer (score 1):

It's headline English, an abbreviated style that, at the least, omits articles and forms of "to be". It keeps headlines brief, so the large type takes up less space, and it adds impact by removing weak words, leaving the words that convey the essential meaning. See https://malcolmsenglishpages.com/situations/newspaper-headline-english/ for examples.