# Infinitive verb as the main verb

Tags: infinitives

I have seen this usage on Twitter and wonder what it exactly means. Is it just an informative exception or a common usage?

Thresa May to take her Brexit roadshow to the north-east

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLjXo.png)

Comment: It's headlinese, which doesn't follow normal English rules. Generally articles and auxiliaries (like _is_ here) are deleted. The idea is to save space.

Comment: It's a phrase, not a sentence. Strictly, doesn't even have to be a grammatically correct phrase for a headline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "Prices to be set..." used in this sentence instead of "Prices will be set..."?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412990/why-is-prices-to-be-set-used-in-this-sentence-instead-of-prices-will-be-se)

Comment: See also [Noun + to + infinitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438173/noun-to-infinitive) and [To + verb in sentence without any other verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209197/to-verb-in-sentence-without-any-other-verb)

Comment: Uh… Batuhan Kavlak, please first accept, Twitter now is as relevant as a piece of paper might have been, 200 years ago…