# To-infinitive in official documents

Tags: grammar

I'm writing an internal policy using some publicly available drafts. In one of them, I encountered a requirement written using to-infinitive like in news titles:

> Network administrators to perform maintenance regularly...

That means that Network administrators *must* or *should* perform maintenance regularly. It looked odd to me. Can to-infinitive be used in such a situation or is it a mistake?

Comment: Closely related: [Why is “Prices to be set…” used in this sentence instead of “Prices will be set…”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412990) -- it's pretty much equivalent to "Network administrators **are** to perform maintenance regularly"

Comment: Yes, I've seen this style used in policies or other sources outlining one's obligations: Children to wake up at 8 am, to have breakfast at...., to brush their teeth before...etcetera. Sometimes it would say: Children ARE to wake up at...Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence says that the admin "is to perform" perform maintenance. Leaving out the verb "is" may be throwing you.  The urgency is not specified. In some contracts and Mil-Spec documents they say one "shall perform" leaving nothing to the imagination. This sounds like a list of duties to be done by those with the designated title. So they likely Should perform them. Why else are they here?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the construction can be used in official documents, am I right? It looks to me like somewhat informal or unclear, so I prefer using shall, must or should. I'd like to know which way is better for documents.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between **shall** (meaning the action is mandatory) and **should** (which means it is recommended). Formal specifications avoid the use of **must** (apparently for reasons of potential ambiguity that are not completely clear to me).

Comment: The _be to `Infinitive`_ construction has deontic modal function: _He is to settle the dispute_ = _He (is the person who) should/must settle the dispute._ Rather like the relative infinitive construction: _the man to fix the starter_  = _the man who should/must fix the starter_. Also like the Latin gerundive construction, as in _Carthago delenda est_ 'Carthage must/should be destroyed'.