# (Noun to verb np) structure and grammar

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I can't understand the grammar and structure of following sentence:
"YouTube to Remove Thousands of Videos Pushing Extreme Views"
I think something is omitted, it should be: "YouTube is to remove..." or "YouTube going to remove..."

What's the structure and grammar of the first sentence?

Comment: It looks like a newspaper headline. These commonly omit words in order to save space.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To + verb in sentence without any other verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209197/to-verb-in-sentence-without-any-other-verb) (the example string OP gives is 'Squall, Tina and Lightning to appear in Final Fantasy Explorers')